# Strongly typed list return from View to fill Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm attempting to pass data around and am having an issue doing it with strongly typed data.

The over all goal is this:

- Index: List of check boxes of all employees. Groups in a table, seperated by working address (easily doable via foreach(string address) + foreach(Employee e where e.Where(address) kind of magic.
- Details of the report. This part should display the list of users selected, ask for some hours and a title. Simple enough.
- Finalize and display. This part should insert the data in to a database and render a pdf.

Here is the Class of which I expect data of an employee to be in. I removed methods in there for the sake of making this shorter:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public List<EmployeeForList> Employees { get; set; }

    public class EmployeeForList
    {
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Building { get; set; }

        public EmployeeForList()
        {
        }

        public EmployeeForList(TXEP.InfoWeb employee)
        {

            this.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
            this.IsChecked = false;
            this.LastName = employee.LastName;
            this.Building = employee.BuildingAddress;
            this.EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeId;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the view code:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("TrainingDetail", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table border="1">
    @foreach (string building in Model.GetUniqueBuildings())
    {
        <tr>
        @foreach (var employee in Model.GetEmployeesFromBuilding(building))
        {
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => @Model.GetEmployee(employee).IsChecked)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => @Model.GetEmployee(employee).LastName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => @Model.GetEmployee(employee).FirstName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => @Model.GetEmployee(employee).EmployeeId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => @Model.GetEmployee(employee).Building)
                @employee.LastName, @employee.FirstName
            </td>
        }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
    <input type="submit" value="sub" />  
}
```

I'm expecting it to return the model above. Instead it return an empty list of Employee's. I'm sure I'm missing something silly but I can't understand what.

The Controller on the receiving end looks like:

```
    public ActionResult TrainingDetail(Models.IndexModel indexModel)
    {
        if (indexModel.Employees == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "EMPTY FOO";
            return View();
        }
        int count = indexModel.Employees.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true).Count();
        ViewBag.Message = count.ToString();

        return View();
    }
```

What I suspect I'm failing to grasp is how can I create an Employee in the View such that it populates a strongly typed list. Or am I misunderstanding the concepts entirely?

It seems to revolve entirely around being a list as I can pass simple data easily -- but this list is empty when I get it, however my Google-fu is failing me and so I beseech you, my fellow brethren, for help.

Comment: MVC does not POST lists in the way you would expect. You will need to format your View so the ModelBinder will be able to tell that your data is part of a list. See [Steve Sanderson's BeginCollectionItem helper won't bind correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568160/steve-sandersons-begincollectionitem-helper-wont-bind-correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe to hydrate a list of entities during model binding the names of the properties of the entity need to be prefixed with an index like so:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Employees[0].IsChecked)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employees[0].LastName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employees[0].FirstName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employees[0].EmployeeId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employees[0].Building)
```

This is how MVC knows to create a new `EmployeeForList` entity and add it to the `Employees` list.

**NOTE:** `model` here would be `IndexModel`.