# mvc 5, model is List, submited model is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I need to submit list of skills. when i try to do this submitted model is null. But in Fidler I see that data was send.

```
public class MvcSkill
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    [StringLength(128, ErrorMessage = "Max length - {0} symbols")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your last name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Choose skill category")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Partial view for each skill (strange input for skill level is bootstrap-star-rating:

```
@using MvcApp.Infrastructure;
@model MvcApp.ViewModels.MvcSkill

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CategoryName)
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CategoryName)
    </td>
    <td>
        <input for="Level" id="@Model.Id" value="@Model.Level" name="Level" type="number" class="rating-loading" data-size="xs" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="1" data-show-clear="false">
    </td>

    @{
        var identity = (CustomIdentity)User.Identity;

        if (identity.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r == "Administrator") != null)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.RouteLink("Edit", new { controller = "Administrator", action = "EditSkill", id = Model.Id })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.RouteLink("Remove", new { controller = "Administrator", action = "RemoveSkill", id = Model.Id })
            </td>
        }
    }
</tr>
```

View for list of skills:

```
@model IList<MvcApp.ViewModels.MvcSkill>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Skills";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Skill", Model))
{
    <table>
        @foreach (var s in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_Skill", s)
        }
    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section scripts{
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/star-rating.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/star-rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        string id = item.Id.ToString();
        <script>
            $(document).on('ready', function () {
                $('#@id').rating({
                    step: 1,
                    defaultCaption: 'Unknown',
                    starCaptions: { 0: 'Unknown', 1: 'Beginner', 2: 'Elementary', 3: 'Intermediate', 4: 'Advanced', 5: 'Profi' },
                    starCaptionClasses: function (val) { return 'text-success'; }
                }).on('rating.change', function (event, value, caption) {
                    Model.Skills.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key.Id.ToString() == id).Value = value;
                });
            });            
        </script>
    }
}
```

And controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(List<MvcSkill> skillModel)
        {
            //Do something...

            return View();
        }
```

Fidler text:
Id=1&Name=c%2B%2B&CategoryName=Programing&Level=5&Id=3&Name=PHP&CategoryName=Programing&Level=3&Id=6&Name=JAVA&CategoryName=Programing&Level=3&Id=7&Name=Name&CategoryName=.Net+Frameworks&Level=5

Comment: You can have a look to [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). He uses the NuGet [BeginCollectionItem HtmlHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). It is designed for posting variable length lists to another MVC controller action.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) - you need a `for` loop of custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `MvcSkill`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually add *indexes* so MVC framework can successfully bind data. Something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Skill", Model))
{
    <table>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Hidden("[" + i + "].Id");
                </td>               
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(i).Name)
                    @Html.Hidden("[" + i + "].Name");
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(i).CategoryName)
                    @Html.Hidden("[" + i + "].CategoryName");
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Or, *as stated in comments* you can use `BeginCollectionItem` (which I personally use). What `BeginCollectionItem` does is, generally it adds *GUIDs* as index fro you. Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) and you can get familiar with it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8568784/1380428).

Comment: @YakovShtykov, I am glad that it helped